# How to return all rows if IN subquery has no rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Following is sample query

```
Select *
  from tb.Users u
 where u.Approved = 1
   and u.userID IN ( SELECT us.UserID us
                       FROM tb.UserStatementes us
                      WHERE us.LogDate between date1 and date2 )
```

I need to select all users that are in th IN clause however if the subquery has not returned records I need to select all users (ie ignore the IN clause)

Comment: you can add that to your existing AND `OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT us.UserID us
                        FROM tb.UserStatementes us
                       WHERE us.LogDate between date1 and date2 )`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Select *
  from tb.Users u
 where u.Approved = 1
   and (
    u.userID IN ( SELECT us.UserID us
                        FROM tb.UserStatementes us
                       WHERE us.LogDate between date1 and date2 
                       )
    or not exists (
        select 1
          from tb.UserStatementes us
          where us.LogDate between date1 and date2
        )
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select *
  from tb.Users u
 where u.Approved = 1
   and ( exists        ( SELECT 1 
                           FROM tb.UserStatementes us
                           WHERE us.LogDate between date1 and date2 
                             AND us.USERID = u.USERID )
         or not exists ( SELECT 1 
                           FROM tb.UserStatementes us
                          WHERE us.LogDate between date1 and date2 )
       )
```